Can offset of swapfile change?
If you want to hibernate using a swapfile, you need to set the resume_offset kernel parameter to the swapfile's offset in the partition. You can find its offset with filefrag -v /swapfile. [1, 2]
I'm concerned about the offset of the swapfile changing without my knowledge. Can this happen? I'm using ext4. As far as I know ext4 can move files to prevent fragmentation. Additionally, can fragmentation of the swapfile itself be a problem? If the swapfile is fragmented, how does the kernel find all its parts just from the resume_offset parameter?

What operating system are you using? Why exactly are you concerned about the offset? Most operating systems automatically handle file fragmentation in some capacity, when it’s applicable, since not all storage devices are effected by file fragmentation


I'm concerned about the offset of the swapfile changing without my knowledge. Can this happen?

It can if you run a defrag tool at any point.
The Syslinux bootloader marks its ldlinux.sys file as "immutable" using chattr to prevent it from being moved. (MS-DOS with FAT used to use the 'System' attribute for the same purpose.)

I'm using ext4. As far as I know ext4 can move files to prevent fragmentation.

It doesn't move anything automatically (I think btrfs is the only one to have autodefrag). It would require manually running e4defrag to make that happen.

Additionally, can fragmentation of the swapfile itself be a problem? If the swapfile is fragmented, how does the kernel find all its parts just from the resume_offset parameter?

The hibernation image is stored as a linked list, with each structure pointing into the next by its sector address.

Thank you! This might be a stupid question, but how is ldlinux.sys being immutable related to the swapfile?
And, just out of curiosity, if btrfs does have autodefrag, does this mean you shouldn't use it to hold a swapfile for hibernation?

They're both types of files that something else references by a fixed sector address. (For example, the syslinux VBR is too small to understand a filesystem so it has the ldlinux.sys sector address embedded in it, so the file must be contiguous and not move.) Btrfs doesn't do anything to active swapfiles – though now that I think of it, neither does e4defrag, as well – the file is essentially immutable after it has been swapon'd. So the concern is only about swapfiles that are inactive during the (manual or auto) defrag process.
